# How to sort values in Elasticseach by latest and earliest date in array using Spring Framework?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, sorting, elasticsearch

I have Spring Boot application and I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`.

I have nested object with list of objects(that contains list of dates), that I have to sort by earliest value of startDate in array and by latest value of endDate.
I didn't find any examples for that.
How could I implement that?

The hierarchy is looking like this:

`mainObject.dateRangeList.[{startDate, endDate}, ...]`

dateRangeList is annotated as

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, name = "date-range-list")
 private List<DateRange> dateRangeList;
```

start and end dates are annotated as

```
@Field(name = "start",
      type = FieldType.Date,
      format = DateFormat.date,
      pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 private LocalDate start;
```

Example of document

```
    {
        "id": "qwe",
        "a": "ABC",
        "c": "qwe",
        "b": "qwe",
        "someFields"...
        "schedule": {
            "z": "qwe",
            "x": false,
            "date-range-list": [
                {
                    "start": "2020-11-01",
                    "end": "2020-12-01"
                }
            ],
            "y": []
        },
        "somefields"...
    }
```

[image: Nested object]

Comment: Could you describe the desired order a little bit more in detail and provide an example? I don't really understand *sort by first value of startDate and last value of endDate*.

Comment: For example [{24-09-2021, 25-09-2021}, {22-09-2021, 28-09-2021}] first element in object is startDate, 2nd - endDate. First sorting of my main object - sort by startDate values starting from earlier date, second - by endDate starting from latest date
@deHaar

Comment: Are those two different sorting orders or do you mean if the startDates are equal, then sort by endDate?

Comment: How does the list of dates look in Java code?

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake in comment. Correct task:
"First sorting of my main object - sort by startDate values using earlier date in array, second - by endDate using latest date" @deHaar

Comment: @deHaar The list of dates look 
 `@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, name = "date-range-list")
  private List<DateRange> dateRangeList;` List contains LocalDate start and end

Comment: Don't really know how to use annotations in order to sort them, but you could write a `Comparator` for `DateRange`s or make `DateRange implements Comparable<DateRange>` and handle the necessary cases, like *if start dates are equal, then sort by end date descending, otherwise sort by start date ascending*, for example.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that for this case better to use Java sorting instead of Elasticsearch) @deHaar

Comment: It's too custom for any built-in sorter, that means best solution would be a `Comparator` (written by you) that you can use in an annotation later (maybe possible).

Comment: But from other hand - I will have to return 9999999(many values) as main objects with many fields. So then I still have to sort that in Java instead of quick sorting using ElasticSearch @deHaar

Comment: Don't know Elastic very well, there might be customization options. You'd probably have to dig deep into its documentation.

Comment: well probably yes) @deHaar

Comment: Can you share a sample document?

Comment: @ms_27 yes, I added example in topic

Comment: @ms_27 maybe I have to use somehow scriptSort in springframework.elasticsearch library?

Comment: Your question asks about using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` constructs directly. I think we should focus on elastic search query first. Can you share the index mapping too? so that anyone can playaround and check on what works for your usecase.

Comment: I am not sure if I can share full index document with all fields, because its private) I sent you the structure of the document with 'schedule' nested object that is needed to solve the task. Do you really need other fields, that are not related to the task? @ms_27

Comment: @ms_27 please, let me know, if I gave you enough info

Comment: No I don't want other fields. It is just how you have mapped the nested documents. Because, afaik, in ES, the nested documents are indexed separately and a parent child relationship is maintained within outer and nested document. So, its important to experiment the stuff.

Comment: I have added image, is it right thing, that you needed? @ms_27

Comment: yes that is what I was asking. I will try this out.

Comment: @ms_27 ok thanks. I'd like to add that basic sorting for this I implemented adding ```.setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder(nestedPath))``` to NativeSearchQueryBuilder